# Как узнать, что загрузка фонового изображения для блока закончена?

Tags: javascript, jquery

По клику на кнопку блоку задаётся свойство `background` в качестве фона картинка.
Фон загружается только после нажатия на кнопку. Как узнать, что фон загружен, и вывести этот блок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете сделать хитро.

Как такового механизма отследить загрузку картинки при установке ее в качестве фона для блока нет. Но что мы можем?

- Загрузить картинку скриптом
- После загрузки всё тем же скриптом установить ее в качестве фона (картинка уже загружена, она возьмется из кэша и повторного запроса не будет)

```js
function loadImage() {

  var src = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/js.png'; // ссылка для картинки
  var img = document.createElement("img"); // создаем абстрактное изображение

  /* функция выполнится после загрузки картинки */
  img.onload = function() {
    imgblock.style.background = "url(" + src + ")"; // устанавливаем картинку как фон
  };

  /* вот тут как раз картинка начнет загружаться */
  img.src = src;
}
```

```css
#imgblock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='imgblock'></div>
<button onclick="loadImage()">Клик</button>
```